# Socket.IO & Redis (Where does it all go?)

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

I have Socket.IO hooked up to a RedisStore such that using "socket.set()" will store its information in my redis database.

It does this by creating some form of random key which I can only assume is the unique identifier for the socket.

My problem is this. From what I can see this data that I save never gets deleted unless I somehow manually delete it. Every new socket is saved and stored but the old ones are never removed unless I do something on disconnect. However this means that if I restart node or have a crash etc this data will persist forever.

My goal is trying to find somewhere to clean the database of old keys. My problem is that I'm having trouble to find a good way to find these old keys.

On idea of a solution I thought of would be to store these key names in a set of some sort. I could then iterate over them and check if they're still in use at start-up. However, as far as I can tell I have no way to find the key being used.

Another though was that I could try and iterate over all keys, but that seems like a bad idea. I also can't properly differentiate the keys they use with keys that I use unless I specifically avoid using keys of a particular length.

So my question is if anyone has a good way to keep my database clean or how can I keep track of the keys that socket.io is using in my database.

Thanks,
Sammy

p.s. If you need any more information or I wasn't clear just tell me and I'll do my best to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is just needing to delete out-of-use keys, why not use Redis' [ttl](http://redis.io/commands/ttl) and [expire](http://redis.io/commands/expire). You can set the expire value on each use, or some such, and set it to be very high. If something goes without use for, say, a week, it will automatically be deleted for you behind the scenes.

Comment: This solves my problem for keys that I add myself, but not kets added by socket.io

If I close a socket while node is running then the socket is removed from the redis database (by socket.io). If node is closed or crashes then this doesn't happen. It just sits in the database forever (unless I'm missing something).

As far as i can tell I can't get the keys used by socket.io. But if I could I could solve this manually (by setting EXPIRE on them).

Comment: Found out that sockets have a property socket.id which lets me do this. Then I'm using expires. Thanks.